# How to Automate Oracle SQL Developer to export a query to csv/xlsx once a day

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm fairly new to SQL and my team has been tasked with running a daily report which requires SQL data. Is there a way to use Oracle SQL Developer to automatically export a query to csv/excel on a daily basis?

Comment: Sure, use SQLcl - the command-line version of SQLDev. Spool to a file using the sqlformat csv, your data. Then use your OS scheduler to kick that off.

Answer (score 0):

The program Oracle SQL Developer itself won't automate it, but there are plenty of options to get it done.

Basically, some computer somewhere needs to have a scheduler that can wake it up and do the work. Some people use their own computers for this, using windows scheduled tasks, cron jobs, or 3rd party programs.

But what "tasks" will your computer run? The task is basically to connect to the database, authenticate, send the Query text, retrieve the results in memory, and then export them as a file. Lot's of people will use python for this, because it can handle all of those steps.

You'll notice that we're already at 2 external "things" that could fail.
(1) your computer,
(2) your python code.

A simpler option, is the oracle database itself. Is it on a remote server that's always running? If so, you might take advantage of that and have *it* do all the work.

You're looking at a few steps, but I think they are easier (you might have to get permissions from an admin, though).

**Specify a file location** - remember, this is on the server, not your computer

```
create or replace directory csv_dir as '/destination/for/results';
```

**Create a stored procedure** - acts like a container for your SQL logic.

```
create or replace procedure write_file is
  file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
begin
  file_handle := utl_file.fopen('CSV_DIR', 'csv_filename.csv', 'w', 32767);
  for rws in (
    select * from t -- your query here
  ) loop
    utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 
      rws.c1 || ',' || rws.c2 || ',' || rws.c3 -- your columns here
    );
  end loop;
  utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
end write_file;
```

**Create a scheduler job** - runs the stored procedure. This is a feature of your Oracle server.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name => 'EXPORT_CSV_J',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'begin write_file; end;',
    number_of_arguments => 0,
    start_date => NULL,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY',
    end_date => NULL,
    enabled => FALSE,
    auto_drop => FALSE);

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
    name => 'EXPORT_CSV_J', 
    attribute => 'logging_level', 
    value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_RUNS);
  
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
    name => 'EXPORT_CSV_J');
END;
```

I borrowed this code from [this website](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search%3Ftag%3Dautomate-the-generation-of-sql-query-output-to-csv) since it has been a while since I did this myself.

If for some reason your database isn't actually Oracle (I know some people use Oracle SQL Developer even though their actual database is something different) then the steps will be similar but the code will be different.